# Form action attribute does not work

Tags: php

There is problem in submitting the form. My form tag looks like-

```
<form method="post" action="classes/action.php" >
```

this doesn't redirect the page..

Any idea??

more code-

```
   <div class="grid_12">

      <div class="grid_6 half-c half_m2" align="center" style="border-radius:100px 0 0 100px">
        <form method="post" action="classes/action.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><label class="eh1 eh1m">Login as Visitor</label> </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><br /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="eh2">Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtVUname" class="etxt1 etxtm1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="eh2">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="txtVPwd" class="etxt1 etxtm1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="btnVLogin" value="Login" style="float: right" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

      </div>

      <div class="grid_6 half-c half_m2" align="center" style="border-radius:0 100px 100px 0">
       <form method="post" action="classes/action.php" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><label class="eh1 eh1m">Login as a Company</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><br /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="eh2">Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCUname" class="etxt1 etxtm1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="eh2">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="txtCPwd" class="etxt1 etxtm1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="btnComLogin" value="Secure Login" style="float: right" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
      </div>
     </div>
```

folder structure looks like--

```
mysite.com
    - classes
            - action.php
    - login.php (containing form)
```

**one more thing.. i can do the same from another page having form and a submit button to redirect on classes/action.php page**

Comment: If i change the form action to something else like-

    <form method="post" action="welcome.php" >

its works but if i use

<form method="post" action="classes/action.php" >

this doesn't work.

Comment: you give us one line of code.

Comment: *"but if i use <form method="post" action="classes/action.php" > this doesn't work"* - So, put that file inside the `classes` folder perhaps?

Comment: and why did you tag as mysql?

Comment: action.php file is already in the folder name "classes"

Comment: then your form needs to be one step before that folder.

Comment: u have submit button for form??

Comment: yes i use a submit button

Comment: can u add complete form??

Comment: may i give u more code..? i m using two forms one one page..

Comment: Use Fiddler (or any other HTTP debugger of your choice, including browser's Network tab in dev tools) to investigate what actually happens. I suspect your relative url is working the way it should and not the way you'd like.

Comment: Where is your form file, is it in the same folder which classes folder in?

Comment: no form file is out side the classes folder..

Comment: can you post the contents of action.php?

Comment: in action.php i check the isset($_POST['btnComLogin']){ code goes here..}

Comment: try my answer and say the output

Comment: @Brian Its too long to post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple mistake only. Replace form action and say me the result

```
 <form method="post" action="../mywebsitename/classes/action.php" >
```

change the action.php to action2.php and try

```
<form method="post" action="../mywebsitename/classes/action2.php" >
```

Comment: action.php file is in the folder name classes

Comment: @Hasan try my updated code. already they have answered . what is the error u r getting ?

Comment: can you post the link which u r getting ?

Comment: my code didn't redirect the page to action.php. after submit the form its on the same page. but if i use ur code then it redirect but shows an error--    
localhost/action.php 404error:object not found

Comment: after using ur updated code the error is-- http://localhost/classes/action.php  and 404http error

Comment: say on thing yoururl  should be localhost/classes/action.php? . am i right?else post the url which u need

Comment: @Hasan : you said action.php is inside classes right ? then what ?

Comment: localhost/mywebsitename/classes/action.php

Comment: @Hasan: i updated now it will work. i will update the exact  solution. soon

Comment: this did not redirect the page to anywhere.. :( like as of my previous problem

Comment: @Hasan: it sholud work. what the output . can you post the url?

Comment: one more thing.. i can do the same from another page having form and a submit button to redirect on classes/action.php page

Comment: not yet but i'll use session when it redirect to to action page.. :) first it should be redirect to action page

Comment: how it can happen like  this i used <form method="post" action="../mywebsitename/classes/action.php" > but you saying that it is moving to  localhost/websitename/login.php ? how

Comment: login.php is the page having the form. after submitting its on the same page. it does not redirect to action.php

Comment: i know what you are saying is write it should redirect to action.php page but unfortunately it does not..

Comment: @Hasan really it is mystery  :)

Comment: i put a file in classes folder name action2.php and update the form action as action="classes/action2.php" and it works.. so it is clear that there is problem to read the action.php file..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<form method="post" action="./classes/action.php">
```

Be careful that file names are case-sensitive in unix!

Comment: check developer console to see if there are any errors in your page

Answer (score 0):

You should return back by .. So if your form file in the same folder contains the classes folder your code will work, if your form file in internal folder like files/form_file.PHP and the folder files in the same classes folder your code will be:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/classes/action.php" >
```

And so on.

Comment: OK,  can you use the full website URL in action to http:\\website.com\classes\action.PHP , please try this?

Comment: its not work.. it redirects to a wrong address like- http://localhost/connectingwater.com/\\connectingwater.com\classes\action.php

Comment: 404 object not found.. :(

Comment: Can you send your login.PHP URL?